# Speeding up a loop to create a long string

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, loops, nsstring

I am creating a very long string by formatting `NSNumber`s in four different arrays:

```
NSString *datos = @"";

for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < [latOut count]; counter++) {
    datos = [datos stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0005f,", [[latOut objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue]]];
    datos = [datos stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0005f,", [[lonOut objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue]]];
    datos = [datos stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld,", [[tipoOut objectAtIndex:counter] integerValue]]];
    datos = [datos stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld\n", [[velocidadOut objectAtIndex:counter] integerValue]]];
}

NSString *curDir = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] currentDirectoryPath];

NSString *path = @"";
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:curDir];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.csv"];

// Y luego lo grabamos
[datos writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

The count is 18,000 entries, and this loop takes almost 2 minutes to complete.

How could I make this much faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your memory consumption is also likely mindblowing. Use a mutable string instead of creating thousands of temporary strings:

```
NSMutableString *datos = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < [latOut count]; counter++) {
    [datos appendFormat:@"%.0005f, %.0005f, %ld, %ld\n", [[latOut objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue], 
                                                         [[lonOut objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue], 
                                                         [[tipoOut objectAtIndex:counter] integerValue], 
                                                         [[velocidadOut objectAtIndex:counter] integerValue]];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both answers makes much faster. Anyway, appendFormat gives a warning (NSString may not respond to -appendFormat). How can I fix this? I would like to leave the code as you did, in just one operation, not four like me

Comment: @AlejandroLuengo: Sorry, speed error on my part. I left `datos` declared as `NSString`, not `NSMutableString`. Now fixed.

Comment: LOL your loop takes less than 1 second to complete. Mine more than 2 minues. That's what I call OP-TI-MI-ZE. Thanks a lot for that!

Answer (score 4):

The main suggestion I see here, since you are working a lot with strings, is to use `NSMutableString` which should be much more efficient:

```
// give a good estimate of final capacity
NSMutableString *datos = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:100000];

for (NSInteger counter = 0; counter < [latOut count]; counter++) {
  [datos appendFormat:@"%.0005f", [[latOut objectAtIndex:counter] floatValue]];
  ...
}
```

This will avoid a lot of unnecessary temporary immutable string allocations.

Comment: `initWithCapacity:` is indeed a good idea here, since a) it seems that Alejandro has a reasonable estimate for the final size and b) that final size is quite big and likely to require a few reallocations otherwise.

Comment: Yes, Josh. I included that since final size it's known. Thanks for that